# Testing equality of variances of two populations

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Suppose you are given two sets of data :

```
 DATA A: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6       (n=5)
 DATA B: 4, 2, 1, 2, 6, 4, 2 (n=7)
```

Is there any way to determine if standard deviation of A equals standard deviation of B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two samples are are as shown in the data vectors below.
We can find their sample variances $S_A^2 = 2.5$ and $S_B^2 = 3.0,$ which
are, respectively, unbiased estimates of population variances
$\sigma_A^2$ and $\sigma_B^2.$

```
A = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6);  B = c(4, 2, 1, 2, 6, 4, 2)
var(A);  var(B)
## 2.5
## 3
```

Then the question is whether 2.5 and 3.0 are sufficiently different
to reject $H_0: \sigma_A^2 = \sigma_B^2$ against $H_a: \sigma_A^2 \ne \sigma_B^2,$   and thus declare $\sigma_A^2$ and $\sigma_B^2$ significantly
different.

**Testing equality of population variances.**

Under $H_0,$ the ratio $F = S_A^2/S_B^2 = 2.5/3.0 = 0.8333$ is distributed
according to Snedecor's F distribution with $5-1=4$ numerator degrees of freedom (df) and $7 - 1 = 6$ denominator df. [This distribution is also called
the 'variance ratio' distribution.]

For a test at the 5% level, the lower critical value $F_L^* = 0.109$ cuts 2.5% of the area under the PDF from the left-hand tail of $F(4,6),$ and the upper critical value $F_U^* = 6.227$ cuts 2.5% of the area from its right-hand tail.
Thus the two parts of the rejection region are to the left of 0.109 and to
the right of 6.227. Our observed value $F = 0.8333$ falls between these two
critical values, and so we cannot reject $H_0.$

```
 qf(.025, 4, 6)
 ## 0.1087274
 qf(.975, 4, 6)
 ## 6.227161
```

In the sketch of the PDF of $F(4,6)$ below, vertical red dotted lines
show the two critical values, and the vertical green line shows the
observed value of the F-statistic.

[image]

Unfortunately, this F-test has has rather poor power. That is, the two
population variances may be different, but this may not be reflected
in sufficiently different sample variances to give convincing 'proof' of
inequality.

Here is what the variance test looks like in R statistical
software; the P-value 0.8994 is considerably above .05 (indicating
no rejection), and the CI includes 0.8333 as a 'reasonable value' of the
variance ratio for samples of these sizes.

```
 var.test(A,B)

 ##        F test to compare two variances

 ## data:  A and B 
 ## F = 0.8333, num df = 4, denom df = 6, p-value = 0.8994
 ## alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is not equal to 1 
 ## 95 percent confidence interval:
 ## 0.1338223 7.6644259 
 ## sample estimates: 
 ## ratio of variances 
 ##          0.8333333
```

---

**Testing the equality of population means.**

Finally, you say you want to know whether variances are equal in order
to do the 'appropriate' test whether population means are equal. My
guess is that you are trying to decide between a 'pooled' two-sample t test
(which assumes population variances equal) and a Welch two-sample t test
(which does not assume them equal).

*My view is that the best statistical
practice is to do the Welch test unless you have very solid prior information
that population variances are equal.* Simulation studies have shown that
a 'hybrid test', which (1) checks for unequal variances with an F-test 
and (2) does the Welch test only when the F-test rejects, is *not* an
optimal procedure (even if you can figure out the *actual* significance level
for the two tests in tandem). It is best just to do the Welch ('separate variances') test from the start. [Of course, if your text or instructor
has told you to do this, it is probably best to comply. But when you are
done with the course, you can remember what best statistical practice is.]

For your data, the Welch two-sample t test fails to reject with P-value 0.3257.
Notice that in R the Welch test is the default. (If you insist on doing
the pooled test, you must use the parameter `var.eq=T` after giving the
two data vectors.) Also, you could see that this is not a pooled test
even if the header didn't say 'Welch': a pooled test would have df = 5 + 7 - 2 = 10; for 'insurance' against the possibility of unequal variances, you
use a smaller df = 9.26 (which some software packages would round down to 9).

```
 t.test(A, B)

 ##        Welch Two Sample t-test

 ## data:  A and B 
 ## t = 1.0377, df = 9.26, p-value = 0.3257
 ## alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0 
 ## 95 percent confidence interval:
 ## -1.170565  3.170565 
 ## sample estimates:
 ## mean of x mean of y 
 ##         4         3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the variance $s^2$ of a sample $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ using the following formula

$s^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{(x_i-\bar{x})^2}$ where $\bar{x}$ is the sample mean.

Data A gives a variance of $2.5$, while data B gives a variance of 3

Comment: Can you determine by the data above only if the population standard deviation (not the sample standard deviation) of the two data are equal?

Comment: No.... you don't have the population standard deviation (we almost never do)

Comment: the data itself cannot provide more than that... that is the purpose of statistics : find a distribution from a sample

Comment: oh okay thanks. I am having problems understanding exam questions. I can't decide if two data samples have equal or unequal population standard deviation

Comment: can you post the exam question ?

Comment: A professor has two classes in psychology: a morning class of 9 students, and an afternoon class of 12 students. On final exams at the same time for all students, the classes received the grades shown in the table below. Can one conclude at .05 significance level, that the average performance of morning class is worse than average performance of afternoon class?                                
Morning class: 73,87,79,75,82,66,95,75,70
Afternoon class:86,81,84,88,90,85,84,92,83,91,53,84

Comment: Sounds like means not standard deviations. Just perform t test on the differences

Comment: I want to know if the population variance of the two samples are equal or not so that I can use the appropriate test.

Comment: Why does that matter ?? You can use a t test to conclude whether or not the average performance of morning class performed worse than the average performance of the afternoon class.. isn't that your question? I'm sorry if i don't follow what your asking.. you cannot find population variances based on those samples

Comment: I thought there were different methods for the t test: One where two population variances equal (where you find the combined Sp standard deviation) and the other with unequal population variances (where you need to find the degree of freedom r or v).

Comment: There _are_ two tests: (1) 'pooled' test when you're sure pop vars are equal (which is very seldom), and (2) Welch test when there is doubt. (Welch test also works if pop vars are equal, sometimes with a tiny loss of power.)